# Where is the bge module file located?

Tags: scripting, game-engine, path

I want to access the bge module's code, but I cannot find it anywhere in the modules folder, or in any other folder from Blender. Where is it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no file in the module directory that gives acces to the `bge` module's code which is written in the source of blender executable.

Comment: I want to add: It is an API (application programming interface). It is implemented within the BGE as native code. The implementation is not Python, it provides access for the Python engine. If you want to see what your calls are resulting in... you need to dig through the Blender/GameEngine Source code (C/C++) as mentioned by Yvain.